# Touchpad stops working randomly on HP Elitebook 840 g3

Tags: 14.04, kernel, touchpad, hp

The mousepad of my laptop stops working after some time, but I can't reproduce it with any particular action.

I found two solutions

1. Switching between virtual console and GUI
2. Restarting the `psmouse` driver

Most probably this is a driver issue, because I am experiencing the same problem if I attach a USB mouse.

This is my `xinput` list

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This may be caused by starting two instances of syndaemon.

Comment: Two instances you mean ps/2 and synPS/2 ?

Comment: I mean that when you manually start `syndaemon` as a stratup application, etc and also turn palm protection on in GUI applet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ps -A | grep syndaemon` terminal command.

Comment: Above command does not output anything

Comment: Then my assumption was wrong.